# Change styling of one component out of 20 instances

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs3

I want to change the background of my components based on the colors of the image inside the component. There are 20 instances of the component on the page, now all 20 instances get the same color, however they should all have their unique color. I don't know how to do this. I tried using inline styling but that doesn't work either.

The color is made when the image is loaded in the component. By this function in the component.

I tried it out with refs but it still changes all 20 cards instead of the 1. And I tried setting unique IDs based on `pokemonid`, but that also did not work.

Here is the code.

The component is called `pokemon-card`.

Component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__front" :style="{'background' : `radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, ${cardCircleColor} 36%, #fff 36%)`}">
      <div class="card__front__cardTop">
        <div class="card__front__cardTop__id"><span></span>{{ id }}</div>
      </div>
      <img class="card__front__img"
           :src="'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/' + id + '.png'"
           alt="pokemonImage" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <div class="card__front__name">
        <h3>{{ name }}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card__back">
      <router-link :to="`/pokemonDetails/${id}`" class="card__back__button">Details</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The color is made when the image is loaded in the component. By this function in the component

```js
methods: {
    //gets color for background based on pokemon image
    getColor() {
      const fac = new FastAverageColor();
      fac.getColorAsync(document.querySelector(`.card__front__img`))
        .then(color => {
          // document.querySelector(`.card__front`).style.background = `radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, ${color.hex} 36%, #fff 36%)`
          this.cardCircleColor = color.hex
        })
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getColor()
  },
```

Relevant CSS of component (the color should be applied to radial-gradient (circle at 50% 0%, # 36%, #fff 36%);)

```scss
&__front {
  transition: all 0.8s;
  //background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, #90aac1 36%, #fff 36%);
  //background-color: $cardBg_color;
```

Parent

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cardContainer">
        <pokemon-card v-for="data in pokemonData.results" :name="data.name" :id="data.id"></pokemon-card>
    </div>

    <div class="PaginationcontrolContainer">
      <div class="paginationControls">
        <div @click="decreasePaginationCounter" class="paginationControls__btn"> &lt </div>
        <input @change="manuallyChangingPaginationIndex" v-model="paginationIndex" type="number">
        <div @click="increasePaginationCounter" class="paginationControls__btn"> > </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: in v-for you should really `:key="data.id"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a good example of why one should not manipulate DOM directly when using Vue.

---

The problem is here:

```js
fac.getColorAsync(document.querySelector(`.card__front__img`))
  .then(...)
```

`document.querySelector('.card__front__img')` will always return the ***first element matching the selector found in the entire DOM***.

Which means that each of the separate `fac` instances are finding the same exact element and using it as color source. The same input will generate the same output, 20 separate times.

Instead, you should follow Vue's guidelines on how to interact with DOM. Use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs).

Specifically:

```html
<template>
  <!-- ... -->
    <img class="card__front__img" ref="image">
</template>
```

```js
  // ...
  getColor() {
    //...
    fac.getColorAsync(this.$refs.image).then(...)
  }
```

Now each component will reference its own `image` ref and, provided they load different images, results should vary.

---

Also, make sure you follow @MichaelMano's advice and `:key` your `v-for`'s with unique identifiers. Although it's not directly connected with the bug you're currently experiencing, it's a common source of subtle bugs, just like yours, which could consume hours, sometimes days, to understand and fix.

---

Note: if my suggestion doesn't fix the error, you should check `image`'s `src` at the time you're running `getColor()`, on each component, and make sure they're what they should be (e.g. `console.log(this.$refs.image.getAttribute('src'))`)

Note for future questions: your question would have been easier to answer if you provided a *runnable* [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thank you very much, that helped. i indeed followed @MicheamMano's advice and added those. your solution worked. did not know that about the dom, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First, dont use query selectors inside vue, use `ref`

Then use that ref to reference the image. Also in `v-for` use `:key`

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
export default {
  setup() {
    const cardImage = ref();
    const cardCircleColor = ref();

    return {
      cardImage,
      cardCircleColor,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getColor();
  },
  methods: {
    getColor() {
      const fac = new FastAverageColor();
      fac.getColorAsync(this.cardImage)
          .then(color => {
            this.cardCircleColor = color.hex
          })
    },
  },
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__front" :style="{'background' : `radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, ${cardCircleColor} 36%, #fff 36%)`}">
      <div class="card__front__cardTop">
        <div class="card__front__cardTop__id"><span></span>{{ id }}</div>
      </div>
      <img
        ref="cardImage"
        class="card__front__img"
        :src="'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/' + id + '.png'"
        alt="pokemonImage" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <div class="card__front__name">
        <h3>{{ name }}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card__back">
      <router-link :to="`/pokemonDetails/${id}`" class="card__back__button">Details</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: is see you use setup() and define refs there, but how do you link those to the elements?
do you maybe have an article about that?

Comment: i tried it out with refs but it still changes all 20 cards instead of the 1.
And i tried setting unique ids based on the id, but that also did not work

Comment: Sorry I did not notice the version/API you were using. The answer below sorted it.